# How to handle expired access token in facebook graph api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am working on web application in which I have implemented Facebook connectivity. User can post to his/her Facebook wall from my site.

I know that access token is required for updating user's status from my site & access token expires after certain amount of time i.e after 2 hrs.

So if user's access token expires user needs to be re-authenticated with Facebook to be able to post on wall. But i want to implement it something like twitter does. Once you connect your Facebook account to Twitter your tweets are posted to Facebook.

I have read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/), but I don't understand PHP.
Can I renew the token? If yes then how? And how twitter implements it?
Please guide me I am new to this stuff.

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the offline_access permission is valid forever or until the user explicitly deauthenticates your app in their facebook application settings.   The way that I check for this in my app is by the following:

```
@$accounts = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_info['uid']."/accounts?access_token=".$fb_info['access_token']));

if($accounts){
    $deauthed=false;
}
```

now reprompt for permissions for a new access token

Comment: a better way is to specify your Deauthorize Callback in your advanced developer settings for your app.  This way when a user de-auths your app, facebook will send a "signed_request" to the URL you specify which is signed with your application secret and then parsed as a json object.  Here is a link to the documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Answer (score 0):

you cant renew the access token.  But you can request the [offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) extended permission.  When your app has this permission you receive an `access_token` that is long-lived.

I seem to remember reading somewhere that it is valid for 30 days... but Im not 100% sure on that figure..

Comment: Then how Twitter manages post to user's Facebook wall? They dont demand the access token frequently.

Comment: i think its not twitter that handles it - rather an application that talks both with the facebook and twitter apis...

Comment: I have also created my application on Facebook.How it will help to do so?

Comment: [this url](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) says that twitter also uses oAuth methods to authenticate.  You would have to make a facebook application that uses the twitter api and their own oAuth methods to update twitter with the contents of your facebook post.